# Why this.pubSubService.changeCategory.subscribe not work?

Tags: angular

Why this.pubSubService.changeCategory.subscribe not work? Thanks.

You may find all codes in https://github.com/aaronchen2k/mobistore-client/blob/master/app/pages/tabs/tabs.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.subscription = this.pubSubService.changeCategory.subscribe(
        category => { 
            console.log('NOT WORK'); 
            this.processCategory(category); 
        }
     );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `PubSubService` to `providers: [...]` of each component, each component will get a different instance of `PubSubService`. If one emits, no one receives the event because the other component is listening on a different `PubSubService` instance.

Add `PubSubService` to `bootstrap(AppComponent, [OtherProviders, PubSubService])` only or alternatively to providers in `AppComponent` but not each component where you want it injected.

Comment: thank you for your quick response, so how can I add this in my ionic project?   https://github.com/aaronchen2k/mobistore-client

Comment: You are right, I use below codes that works well, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, forgot it's about Ionic. I don't use Ionic myself. Add it to `@App({ ..., providers: [PubSubService]})`

Answer (score 0):

```
static getInstance() {
    if (PubSubService.instance == null) {
        PubSubService.isCreating = true;
        PubSubService.instance = new PubSubService();
        PubSubService.isCreating = false;
    }

    return PubSubService.instance;
}
```